# Is it possible to have Ubuntu only on the flash stick?

Tags: system-installation

What I mean by that is that I want to try Ubuntu, but I also want to keep my HP Desktop at the same time. Is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it will do by default. Just boot the flash drive and press "try." If you decide you like it but still want to keep your Windows desktop around, you can also install it *in addition* to windows on the same hard drive. Just look up "ubuntu dual boot windows" or similar to see how to do that.